# Understanding the syntax in this merge function

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner at Haskell and have a question about the following `merge` function. In the following code we get two sorted lists as input and we should merge them together such that the output list is also sorted.

```
merge :: [int] -> [int] -> [int]
merge [] [] = []
merge x [] = x
merge [] x = x
--merge xs     []     = xs
--merge []     ys     = ys
merge (a:as) (b:bs)
 | a<= b = a : (merge as (b:bs))
 |otherwise = b : (merge (a:as) bs)
```

I have seen two versions of this code.

Let us say that `x` represents the first element of the list and when we want to merge one element with an empty list the result is going to be a list with one element. Because of what we defined in the function's head and representation of `x` or `xs` or `ys`, we don't need to write them in this way `[x]` or `(x:)`?

Comment: Is your question: "What is the difference between `merge x [] = x` and `merge xs [] = xs`"?

Comment: If you write `f [x] [] = [x]`, that only handles the case where the first argument has length 1, and the second argument is the empty list. If you write `f x [] = x`, that handles the case where the first argument is any arbitrary list, and the second argument is the empty list (here `x` is the whole list, not just an element).

Comment: Nit: `[int] -> [int] -> [int]` should be `[Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]`. (Either you haven't compiled this code, as it would complain about a missing `Ord` instance, or `int` is just a typo for `Int` in the question.)

Comment: If you list `merge (a:as) (b:bs)` first, you only need one base case: `merge x y == x ++ y`.  Merging two lists where one or both are empty is equivalent to just concatenating the two lists.